# Echarts Legend Not Appearing Using Dataset & Dimensions

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm using the [Echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) library. For some reason, the legend isn't appearing in this simple chart using dataset and dimensions.

I've been stuck for quite a long time, have tried all kinds of examples but to no avail. Please help!

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jcgqfns8/

```js
// based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

        // specify chart configuration item and data
        var option = {
            dataset: [{
                source: [
                    ['Test1', 10],
                    ['Test2', 20]
                ],
                dimensions: ['Category', 'Value']
            },
            {
                source: [
                    ['Test1', 15],
                    ['Test2', 25]
                ],
                dimensions: ['Category', 'Value2']
            }],
            xAxis: [{ type: 'category' }, { type: 'category' }],
            yAxis: [{ position: 'left' }, { position: 'right' }],
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    encode: {
                        x: 'Category',
                        y: 'Value'
                    },
                    datasetIndex: 0,
                    yAxisIndex: 0
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    encode: {
                        x: 'Category',
                        y: 'Value2'
                    },
                    datasetIndex: 1,
                    yAxisIndex: 1
                }
            ],
            color: ["#c22e34", "#e7b603", "#0097da", "#2b821e", "#035daa", "#339ca8"]
        };

        // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
        myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- prepare a DOM container with width and height -->
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add legend to the option object. and give names to series objects.

```
 var option = {
        dataset: [{
            source: [
                ['Test1', 10],
                ['Test2', 20]
            ],
            dimensions: ['Category', 'Value']
        },
        {
            source: [
                ['Test1', 15],
                ['Test2', 25]
            ],
            dimensions: ['Category', 'Value2']
        }],
        legend: {}, //need this to show legend
        xAxis: [{ type: 'category' }, { type: 'category' }],
        yAxis: [{ position: 'left' }, { position: 'right' }],
        series: [
            {
                    name: 'legend1', //give a name to series
                type: 'line',
                encode: {
                    x: 'Category',
                    y: 'Value'
                },
                datasetIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'legend2',
                encode: {
                    x: 'Category',
                    y: 'Value2'
                },
                datasetIndex: 1,
                yAxisIndex: 1
            }
        ],
        color: ["#c22e34", "#e7b603", "#0097da", "#2b821e", "#035daa", "#339ca8"]
    };
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycn3erxk/)